# SQL Subquery Questions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine these 2 queries in such a way to determine who the PI is that owns equipment (>$100K value).  I have the ability to find all the equipment one PI owns that is greater then 100k.  I also have the ability to see all the PIs.  I just cannot get these 2 queries to combine.  I have tried with a WHERE subquery and an EXIST subquery.  I want to be able to find all the equipment (matched with its PI owner) where the PI exists in query #2.

**Query #1 for finding equipment of a specific PI**

```
select Account_No,Inventory_No,Building_No,Room_No,CDDEPT,Location,Normalized_MFG,Manufacturer_Name,Normalized_Model,Name,Serial_Code,CONCAT( '$', FORMAT( Cost, 2 ) ) as Cost, Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Active 
from Temp_Equipment_Inventory.Equipment_Inventory_Normalized, `paul`.`ROOM`, `paul`.`BLDG`, `paul`.`LABORATORY`, `paul`.`PERSON` 
where (`PERSON`.`ID` = `LABORATORY`.`PI_ID` OR `PERSON`.`ID` = `LABORATORY`.`SUPV_ID`) 
AND `LABORATORY`.`RM_ID` = `ROOM`.`ID` 
AND `LABORATORY`.`ACTIVE` = '1' 
AND `ROOM`.`BLDG_ID` = `BLDG`.`ID` 
AND ((
`BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Building_No 
AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Building IS NULL 
AND (`BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` != '1023' AND `LABORATORY`.`OTHER_LEVEL` != '1' AND `ROOM`.`RMNUM` != '0199')
)OR (
`BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Building AND 
(`BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` != '1023' AND `LABORATORY`.`OTHER_LEVEL` != '1' AND `ROOM`.`RMNUM` != '0199')
)) 
AND ((
`ROOM`.`RMNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Room_No 
AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Room IS NULL
)OR (
`ROOM`.`RMNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Room
)) 
AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Active !=0 
AND SurplusPending != '1'
AND Cost >= 100000 
AND `PERSON`.`CANNUM`='810010787'
```

**Query 2 that finds all the PIs**

```
select distinct i.CAN
from CGWarehouse.CCGV10WC w
inner join CGWarehouse.CCGV10IC i
on w.PROJECT_NUMBER=i.SPONSORED_PROJECT
and w.SEQUENCE_NUMBER=i.PROJECT_SEQUENCE
where w.STATUS='A'
and i.PRIN_INVEST_CODE='Y'
and i.DEL_CODE!='Y'
and i.CAN IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Which columns of the two queries are you hoping to join on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the `IN` keyword in your WHERE clause?

Forgive me, but I had to clean up the formatting of your query a little...it's kinda my OCD thing:

```
SELECT
    Account_No,
    Inventory_No,
    Building_No,
    Room_No,
    CDDEPT,
    Location,
    Normalized_MFG,
    Manufacturer_Name,
    Normalized_Model,
    Name,
    Serial_Code,
    CONCAT('$', FORMAT( Cost, 2 )) AS Cost,
    Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Active
FROM
    Temp_Equipment_Inventory.Equipment_Inventory_Normalized a,
    `paul`.`ROOM`,
    `paul`.`BLDG`,
    `paul`.`LABORATORY`,
    `paul`.`PERSON` 
WHERE
    (`PERSON`.`ID` = `LABORATORY`.`PI_ID` OR `PERSON`.`ID` = `LABORATORY`.`SUPV_ID`) 
    AND `LABORATORY`.`RM_ID` = `ROOM`.`ID` 
    AND `LABORATORY`.`ACTIVE` = '1' 
    AND `ROOM`.`BLDG_ID` = `BLDG`.`ID` 
    AND (
        (
            `BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Building_No 
            AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Building IS NULL 
            AND `BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` != '1023'
            AND `LABORATORY`.`OTHER_LEVEL` != '1'
            AND `ROOM`.`RMNUM` != '0199'
        ) OR (
            `BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Building
            AND `BLDG`.`BLDGNUM` != '1023'
            AND `LABORATORY`.`OTHER_LEVEL` != '1'
            AND `ROOM`.`RMNUM` != '0199'
        )
    ) 
    AND (
        (
            `ROOM`.`RMNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Room_No 
            AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Room IS NULL
        ) OR (
            `ROOM`.`RMNUM` = Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Actual_Room
        )
    ) 
    AND Equipment_Inventory_Normalized.Active !=0 
    AND SurplusPending != '1'
    AND Cost >= 100000 
    AND `PERSON`.`CANNUM` IN ( /* this assumes that the `PERSON`.`CANNUM` column matches up with the CGWarehouse.CCGV10IC.CAN column */
        SELECT DISTINCT i.CAN
        FROM
            CGWarehouse.CCGV10WC w
            INNER JOIN CGWarehouse.CCGV10IC i ON w.PROJECT_NUMBER=i.SPONSORED_PROJECT AND w.SEQUENCE_NUMBER=i.PROJECT_SEQUENCE
        WHERE
            w.STATUS='A'
            AND i.PRIN_INVEST_CODE='Y'
            AND i.DEL_CODE!='Y'
            AND i.CAN IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This gives me the results I am looking for.